# Как сделать предупреждение об ошибке при отправке пустого input'a в Angular

Tags: html, angular

есть input форма с отправкой текста в базу.При нахождении слова возвращается массив с данными, при написании слова с ошибкой или несуществующего возвращается пустой массив. В шаблоне сделал два ngIf с проверкой на размерность массива и вывод. 
Вопрос в том,как добавить 3 пункт,если ищешь пустое значение?

HTML

```
<div class="field">
 <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="text" />
  <div>
    <i class="fa fa-times" type="submit" (click)="clear()"></i>
  </div>
  <div>
    <i class="fa fa-search" type="submit" (click)="search()"></i>
  </div>
</div>



 <div *ngIf="SlidesFinded.length != 0">

   <table class='table'>
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Slide Id</th>
      <th> Presentation Id </th>
      <th>Slide Text</th>

     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr *ngFor="let Slide of SlidesFinded;">
      <td>{{ Slide.idSlide }}</td>
      <td>NULL</td>
      <td [innerHTML]="Slide.textSlide | highlight: text"></td>

    </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>


 <div *ngIf="SlidesFinded == 0">
 <div>
   <p>  No matches found with <b>{{text}}</b> </p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В чем сложность?

```
<div *ngIf="!text.length">
    <p>Please, fill the search input!</p>
</div>
```

Либо же можно показывать этот текст не сразу, а после того как юзер нажмет на иконку поиска (`fa-search`), для этого заведем отдельную переменную:

```typescript
@Component({ ... })
class ... {
    public text: string | null = null;

    public inputIsEmpty = false;

    public search(): boolean | void {
        // Если длина введеннего текста `0`
        if (!this.text.length) {
            return this.inputIsEmpty = true;
        }

        // Тут вы сеттите `SlidesFinded`
    }
}
```

В шаблоне же будем показывать предупреждение если юзер нажал на кнопку и там пусто:

```
<div *ngIf="inputIsEmpty">
    <p>Please, fill the search input!</p>
</div>
```

Но возникает ситуация, если юзер нажмет на кнопку и поле окажется пустым, то `inputIsEmpty` останется `true`, нам нужно тогда добавить обработчик события, который будет ставить значение `false`, в случае если длина `value > 0`:

```typescript
@Component({ ... })
class ... {
    public text: string | null = null;

    public inputIsEmpty = false;

    public search(): boolean | void {
        // Если длина введеннего текста `0`
        if (!this.text.length) {
            return this.inputIsEmpty = true;
        }

        // Тут вы сеттите `SlidesFinded`
    }

    public checkLength(value: string): void {
        this.inputIsEmpty = !value.length;
    }
}
```

В шаблоне на `input` повесьте обработчик:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="text" (keyup)="checkLength($event.target.value)" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
```

Если отойти в сторону от такого усложнения, то просто воспользуйтесь первым вариантом (`*ngIf="!text.length"`), а в метод `search` добавьте проверку и выход из функции, если длина равна 0:

```typescript
public search(): void {
    if (!this.text.length) {
        return;
    }

    // Тут делаем запрос к API, если `text.length > 0`
}
```